# NodeMCU-PyFlasher-1.0.0.exe terminates after a few seconds

Tags: lua, nodemcu

Two days ago, everything was fine. I could run NodeMCU-PyFlasher-1.0.0.exe and flash firmware onto nodeMCU boards (WeMos D1 mini or NodeMCU boards).

Today I wanted to re-flash a board. When I started NodeMCU-PyFlasher-1.0.0.exe the exe terminated itself after a few seconds! Huh? How could this be? What the heck could be the reason for this?

Comment: Never heard anything like that. You start it and it crashes after a few seconds without any user interaction (typing, button pressing, etc.)? How about newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fully solved. I use BitDefender Internetsecurity 2017 as protection suit.
After adding the Py-flasher-exe to the Ransomware-whitelist the problem went away.
(I hope this time my answer to THIS question matches the SO-standards)